# basic gridview android problem. It does not show anything

Tags: android, gridview

i am currently in the middle of making a basic gridview with custom layout. although i am only showing text in the gridview for now. i follow some tutorial online and follow everything step by step, i dont get any error from the android studio and i run it. But when i run it, it only show a blank white page. i did initialize the adapter this time, but it still show nothing. help what did i miss in this.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firsttext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ButtonSize"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <GridView
        android:layout_below="@+id/firsttext"
        android:id="@+id/firstList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

gridlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gridtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textSize="@dimen/ButtonSize" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

gridadapter.java

```
public class gridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    String[] names;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public gridAdapter(Context context,String[] names) {
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return names[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View gridView = convertView;
        if (convertView != null){
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            gridView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridlist,null);

        }

        TextView textView = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.gridtext);
        textView.setText(names[position]);
        return gridView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String[] Names = {"great","good","average","great","good","average","great","good","average","great","good","average","great","good","average","great","good","average"};
    GridView grid;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.firstList);

        gridAdapter adapter = new gridAdapter(this,Names);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `match_parent` in your gridlist and `TextView`'s `layout_heiht` repleace it by `wrap_content` and set special color for your `TextView` except for white color.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to: in gridadapter:

```
if (convertView == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        gridView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridlist, parent, false); 
}
```

Comment: it still give me a blank space

Comment: Oh and by the way, do you still have black text color? Otherwise..Hm, I don't have ideas anymore, try to follow this tutorial: check especially adapter and getView method in adapter. : https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/android/grid_view_custom_adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

In adapter change this :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridlist,null);
        TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridtext);
        textView.setText(names[position]);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **RecyclerView** instead of GridView in future. Your problem is with setting color for TextView, check to set **textColor** to black

Comment: i did, change it to black. still the same result